# How to check values inside enum class?

Tags: java, android, json, enum-class

I wanted to check if the tags returned from a json object has one of the values inside an enum class.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
            AnalysisResult result = gson.fromJson(data, AnalysisResult.class);
for(Enum p : Enum.values()){
    if(p.name().equals(result.tags)){
        Intent in1 = new Intent(Analyze.this,  Analyze2.class);
        startActivity(in1);
    }else {
        for (final Caption caption : result.description.captions) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    speakOut("Result:" + caption.text);  
                }
            }, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Enum class

```
public enum Enum {
    person,
    people,
    people_baby,
    people_crowd,
    people_group,
    people_hand,
    people_many,
    people_portrait,
    people_show,
    people_tattoo,
    people_young
}
```

This are the returned tags...

> "tags":["teddy","indoor","clothing","necktie","person","bear","wearing","green","brown","stuffed","sitting","man","bow","neck","face","shirt","blue","hat","close","grey","laying","black","glasses","head","bed","white","holding","cat","sleeping"]}

My problem is that it always goes to the else statement. What do you think is wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the type of result.tags?

Comment: json object @cppbeginner

Comment: No it's not :) It's an AnalysisResult object, and it has a field named 'tags'. What is the object type of `tags`? Any way, you can't use equals between a String and an Array (or whatever it is). You need to iterate all the tags for every `p.name()` if you want to use `equals()`.

Comment: I'll write a code sample as an answer, but please post your AnalysisResult object so I can see the type of the `tags` object.

Comment: Its a  List<Tag> :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to achieve here, And I don't know what is this 'Tag' object, but I guess you want to do something like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
AnalysisResult result = gson.fromJson(data, AnalysisResult.class);
boolean hasTag = false;
for (Tag t : result.tags) {
    if (Enum.hasTag(t.getTagName())) {
        hasTag = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (hasTag) {
    Intent in1 = new Intent(Analyze.this, Analyze2.class);
    startActivity(in1);
} else {
    for (final Caption caption : result.description.captions) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                speakOut("Result:" + caption.text);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

And your Enum like this:

```
public enum Enum {
    person,
    people,
    people_baby,
    people_crowd,
    people_group,
    people_hand,
    people_many,
    people_portrait,
    people_show,
    people_tattoo,
    people_young;

    public static boolean hasTag(String tag) {
        for (Enum e : values()) {
            if (e.name().equals(tag))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```